# SXA[ResolveRenderingDatasource] is not cached on CD configuration

Tags: sxa

The SXA[ResolveRenderingDatasource] is not cached if you configure a site grouping node for a CD configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use Sxa Site Grouping for CM and CD configuration; please enable "Enable Preview" for the CD configuration. Otherwise, the cache doesn't work for SXA[ResolveRenderingDatasource]

**This is an SXA 1.7.1 bug**

[image]